# What should I be researching to solve this problem?

Tags: optimization

This week's ["riddler classic"](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/when-will-your-house-collapse-should-you-take-a-construction-contract/) on [$538$](http://fivethirtyeight.com/) is quite the puzzler (as the riddler classic always is). However, I can usually deduce solutions by researching relevant material or just using what's already up in the 'ol noggin. The question states:

> Consider four towns arranged to form the corners of a square, where each side is $10$ miles long. You own a road-building company. The state has offered you $\$28$ million to construct a road system linking all four towns in some way, and it costs you $\$1$ million to build one mile of road. Can you turn a profit if you take the job?
>
> Extra credit: How does your business calculus change if there were five towns arranged as a pentagon? Six as a hexagon? Etc.?

I don't need a solution to the problem (as that's the fun!), just want a jumping off point. Simply was wondering how to classify the problem. I've been trying to find similar problems and whatnot to help me along, but I'm struggling. I considered graph theory right off the bat, but there's no nodes to work with! I've also thought of using Lagrange Multipliers, but I'm not quite sure that's applicable here. Lastly, I even considered using mathematica to basically drop particles on a polygon then apply graph theory to that, but that seems rather over the top.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 28 is very suspiciously close to $20\sqrt{2}$, which is the sum of the lengths of the 2 diagonals (which would be a suitable road network except that it costs slightly too much). Perhaps you can cut corners a little bit by drawing diagonal lines that meet not quite in the center, and then draw a vertical line between the two intersection points you get.

Comment: Indeed that last idea will work, with not very much money to spare. I will leave the details to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What should I be researching to solve this problem?

My at-a-glance guess: **Steiner minimal trees**.

See, e.g., Gilbert and Pollak's (1968) [**Steiner Minimal Trees**](http://amadeus.ecs.umass.edu/mie373/gilbert_polak.pdf) (pdf) or Courant and Robbins' (1941) "What is mathematics?" as mentioned in the blog post [**here**](https://thatsmaths.com/2015/01/29/the-steiner-minimal-tree/).

---

**Side-note:** Gilbert-Pollak's $\sqrt{3}/2$ "Steiner ratio conjecture" [at the end of p. 23 above] was believed to have been proved successfully; however, an error was later discovered.

**Cf.** [**MO 144081**](https://mathoverflow.net/q/144081) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for this! That’s just what I was looking for!

Comment: @JosephEck You're welcome. I had Henry Pollak as a professor for a couple of courses earlier in the decade [in fact, he is still teaching as of Spring 2018... at age 90!] which is how I learned of Steiner trees in the first place. Good luck with your solution submission.

Comment: I'm surprised to see that my ad hoc idea "draw diagonals, split the central vertex in two, connect these two vertices with a vertical line, continue pulling those two vertices apart until doing so makes it worse" is actually optimal in this particular case.

Comment: @Ian I think I rigged up an exact answer in Desmos (Spoiler? alert): [**link**](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gpklmxekuu)

Comment: **FWIW:** The [follow-up Riddler](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/the-case-of-the-smudged-secret-message/) mentions Steiner Minimal Trees as well as the "What is mathematics?" reference above. [The optimal decision accords with my previous comment's pointer to Desmos.]